# How to connect to 802.1x secured wired student dorm network with Fedora?

Tags: fedora, 802.1x

I'm in student dorm and I installed Linux Fedora on my external HDD. However, my dorm has 802.1x security and requires authentication in order to connect to it. My university has provided shell scripts, however, they don't work and students use SecureW2 program in order to connect. How can I connect, should I use this program on Fedora too? Thank you.

Comment: The most common tool would be wpa_supplicant.

Answer (score 0):

To assume you know or can parse the credentials from the scripts:

802.1x is merely just like any other password secured network in the logic of logging in, however they often need a certificate which may be failing to download/install with mentioned scripts.  If you can get the IT folks to provide a link to them in a static location download them and manually select them in the necessary fields in the connection options.